# HOW TO USE MIT-ROS-PACKAGE!

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,
I'm trying to use the demo packages created by MIT(http : //www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos), however, I don't know where to get the packages, I saw a address listed like: Version Control: https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg, should I use “svn co [https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg”](https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg%E2%80%9D) or "apt-get install [https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg"](https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg%22)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59601/how-to-use-mit-ros-package!/) by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The installation instructions are pretty extensive although there are no fuerte or groovy instructions. Which part you don't get?
I think you should use rosinstall ~/ros_workspace ~/ros_workspace/kinect_demos.rosinstall

*The rosinstall documentation is rather vague indeed,I don't get why your are send back to installing ros page when you are looking for documentation.*

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on 2013-03-30**:
@davinci, I was trying to use MIT-DEMO in GROOVY,  so I didn't see the command "rosinstall ~/ros_workspace ~/ros_workspace/kinect_demos.rosinstall", now I changed my ROS back to electric and followed the tutorial(http : //www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos/electric), however, in the step

**Comment by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on 2013-03-30**:
@davinci, silly number limiter! In the step "Validate certificate from MIT CSAIL's svn",  in the terminal, it seems that I should enter the Client certificate filename(it shows like: Authentication realm: https://svn.csail.mit.edu:1443
Client certificate filename: ), so how to deal with it? THX!

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-03-31**:
https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/ does seem to work, perhaps try that? Otherwise contact the maintainer of the package.

**Comment by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on 2013-03-31**:
@davinci , https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/  works, however, followed the tutorials http ://www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos/electric, in step 7, I always get the error like:

**Comment by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on 2013-03-31**:
@davinci, svn: URL 'https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/trunk' doesn't exist
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'motion_planning_common' : [motion_planning_common] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/trunk version

**Comment by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on 2013-03-31**:
@davinci, I find that at the website of  https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks, the motion_planning_common do not exist, maybe it has been removed, but how can I sole this problem?THX!

**Comment by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on 2013-03-31**:
"solve", not "sole", silly spelling mistake.

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-21**:
@DavidXiong, have you managed to install the package properly? Have you tried to solve the ( Authentication realm: https://svn.csail.mit.edu:1443 Client certificate filename: )?